# Type aliasing to avoid name clash in type refinement

Tags: scala, types, namespaces, alias

Can I use aliasing so I don't need to change either of the type parameter/member in the following name clash situation:

```
trait Bar {
  type A
}

trait Foo {
  def get[A]: Option[Bar { type A = A }]  // "illegal cyclic reference"
}
```

I know I can write

```
trait Foo {
  def get[A1]: Option[Bar { type A = A1 }]
}
```

But I would really prefer not to change the type name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. do something like this:

```
trait Bar {
  type A
}

trait Foo {
  type M[X] = Bar { type A = X }
  def get[A]: Option[M[A]]
}
```

Or inline:

```
def get[A]: Option[({ type X[Y] = Bar { type A = Y }})#X[A]] = ???
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
def get[A]: Option[({ type A1 = A; type X = Bar { type A = A1 }})#X] = ???
```