# In Scala how can I explicitly refer to an enclosing local scope?

Tags: scala, variables, scope

Here's a common annoyance for me:

```
trait Foo {
    val x: Int
}

def foo(x: Int) = new Foo {
    val x = x // <-- Here
}
```

I probably run into this about once every 20 minutes when coding Scala.

The solutions that I am aware of, and their respective deficiencies, are:

- Enclose the local declaration in an object which can be named -- Doesn't work for parameters.
- Make an alias -- Verbose if you need to preserve the path dependent type.
- Use a proxy constructor -- Cumbersome in the presence of dependently typed fields.

Are there any others?

Comment: Can you explain why the alias does not work? for example: trait Foo 

  def foo(x: Int) = new Foo { thisfoo=>
    val thisfoo.x:Int = x // <-- Here
  }

Comment: @LaloInDublin Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be legal syntax.

Comment: You just defined x second time - so you overridden original declaration. x from trait does not exist any more.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375857/type-aliasing-to-avoid-name-clash-in-type-refinement)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use this cheesy approach:

```
def foo(x: Int): Foo = {
  val x1 = x
  new Foo {
    val x = x1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
trait Foo {
    val x: Int
}

object Foo {
    def apply(xt: Int) = new Foo { val x = xt }
}

def foo(xt: Int) = Foo(xt) // <-- Here
```

Comment: That is indeed a good idea. Unfortunately it is also cumbersome in the presence of dependent types. I will add it to the list.